# How to use Parameters to convert to proper data types. with SQL Query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to save some values to data table in MS SQL , but i have some problem with the Data types . i need to use Parameters to convert those values to proper data types

this is my table ,,,

[Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FLfH.jpg)

this is the code that i'm using to pass values to the database ,, i need to use Parameters to convert data, please help me to do it ...

```
private void InsertRec(StringCollection sc)
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        var sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
        var splitItems = (string[])null;
        foreach (string item in sc)
        {
            const string sqlStatement =
                "INSERT INTO DEL_PurchasesLines1 (DealerCode,InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,ItemIdentityCode,PurchasingPrice,DiscountRate,Discount,IssueMode,Qty,Total,ExpireDate,BatchNumber,UploadedStatus,InsertedDate,UploadedDate,Force,Principle,NewTotal) VALUES";

            if (item.Contains(","))
            {
                splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}','{12}','{13}','{14}','{15}','{16}','{17}','{18}'); ", sqlStatement, splitItems[0], splitItems[1], splitItems[2], splitItems[3], splitItems[4], splitItems[5], splitItems[6], splitItems[7], splitItems[8], splitItems[9], splitItems[10], splitItems[11], splitItems[12], splitItems[13], splitItems[14], splitItems[15], splitItems[16], splitItems[17]);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Script", "alert('Records Successfuly Saved!');", true);

        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

this is how i take the values in to query.

```
    protected void btnSaave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
        if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var dtDealerCode = txtIDealerCode.Text;
                    var dtInvoiceNo = txtInvoiceNumber.Text;
                    var dtInvoiceDate = txtInvoiceDate.Text;
                    var dtItemIdentityCode = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("ItemCode");
                    var dtPurchasingPrice = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("UnitPrice");
                    var dtDiscountRate = txtDiscount.Text;
                    var dtDiscount = txtProductDiscount.Text;
                    var dtIssueMode = ddlIssueMode.SelectedValue;
                    var dtQty = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("Quantity");
                    var dtTotal = (Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("GetTotal");
                    var dtExpireDate = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("ExpiaryDate");
                    var dtBatchNumber = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("Batch");
                    var dtUploadedStatus = txtInvoiceDate.Text;
                    var dtInsertedDate = "1";
                    var dtUploadedDate = txtInvoiceDate.Text;
                    var dtForce = txtForce.Text;
                    var dtPrinciple = txtPrinciple.Text;
                    var NewTotal = (Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("GetQuantity");

                    sc.Add(dtDealerCode + "," + dtInvoiceNo + "," + dtInvoiceDate + "," + dtItemIdentityCode.Text + "," + dtPurchasingPrice.Text + "," + dtDiscountRate + "," + dtDiscount + "," + dtIssueMode + "," + dtQty.Text + "," + dtTotal.Text + "," + dtExpireDate + "," + dtBatchNumber.Text + "," + dtUploadedStatus + "," + dtInsertedDate + "," + dtUploadedDate + "," + dtForce + "," + dtPrinciple + "," + dtPrinciple + "," + NewTotal.Text);
                    rowIndex++;
                }

                InsertRec(sc);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to build a method that asks for the specific values it expects, either by having an parameter for each item or via a class type, ie either this:

```
private void InsertRec(DEL_PurchasesLines1 lineToInsert)
```

where `DEL_PurchasesLines1` is a class you will create (named after the table), or this:

```
private void InsertRec(string DealerCode,string InvoiceNo,DateTime InvoiceDate,
            string ItemIdentityCode,decimal PurchasingPrice, decimal DiscountRate,
            decimal Discount,string IssueMode,decimal Qty,decimal Total,
            DateTime ExpireDate,string BatchNumber,string UploadedStatus,
            string InsertedDate,DateTime UploadedDate,string Force,
            decimal Principle,decimal NewTotal)
```

FWIW, that many columns in a single table almost always means something is wrong with the table design, but I'll leave that alone for now. Going with the second method, your button click would look like this:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["CurrentData"] == null) return;
    DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];
    if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count == 0) return;

    int rowIndex = 0;

    var dtDealerCode = txtIDealerCode.Text;
    var dtInvoiceNo = txtInvoiceNumber.Text;
    var dtInvoiceDate = DateTime.Parse(txtInvoiceDate.Text);
    var dtDiscountRate = decimal.Parse(txtDiscount.Text);
    var dtDiscount = decimal.Parse(txtProductDiscount.Text);
    var dtIssueMode = ddlIssueMode.SelectedValue;
    var dtUploadedStatus = DateTime.Parse(txtInvoiceDate.Text);
    var dtInsertedDate = "1"; //Really? 
    var dtUploadedDate = DateTime.Parse(txtInvoiceDate.Text);
    var dtForce = txtForce.Text;
    var dtPrinciple = decimal.Parse(txtPrinciple.Text);

    for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var dtItemIdentityCode = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("ItemCode");
        var dtPurchasingPrice = decimal.Parse((Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("UnitPrice"));
        var dtQty = decimal.Parse((Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("Quantity"));
        var dtTotal = decimal.Parse((Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("GetTotal"));
        var dtExpireDate = DateTime.Parse((Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("ExpiaryDate"));
        var dtBatchNumber = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("Batch");
        var NewTotal = decimal.Parse((Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("GetQuantity"));

        InsertRec(dtDealerCode,dtInvoiceNo,dtInvoiceDate,dtItemIdentityCode,
            dtPurchasingPrice,dtDiscountRate,dtDiscount,dtIssueMode,dtQty,
            dtTotal,dtExpireDate,dtBatchNumber,dtUploadedStatus,dtInsertedDate,
            dtUploadedDate,dtForce,dtPrinciple,NewTotal);

        rowIndex++;
    }
}
```

To bring it all together, `InsertRec()` will look like this:

```
private void InsertRec(string DealerCode,string InvoiceNo,DateTime InvoiceDate,
            string ItemIdentityCode,decimal PurchasingPrice, decimal DiscountRate,
            decimal Discount,string IssueMode,decimal Qty,decimal Total,
            DateTime ExpireDate,string BatchNumber,string UploadedStatus,
            string InsertedDate,DateTime UploadedDate,string Force,
            decimal Principle,decimal NewTotal)
{

    const string sqlStatement =
            "INSERT INTO DEL_PurchasesLines1 (" +
              "DealerCode,InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,ItemIdentityCode,PurchasingPrice,DiscountRate,Discount,IssueMode,Qty,Total,ExpireDate,BatchNumber,UploadedStatus,InsertedDate,UploadedDate,Force,Principle,NewTotal" + 
            ") VALUES (" +
              "@DealerCode, @InvoiceNo, @InvoiceDate, @ItemIdentityCode, @PurchasingPrice, @DiscountRate, @Discount, @IssueMode, @Qty, @Total, @ExpireDate, @BatchNumber, @UploadSTatus, @InsertedDate, @UploadedDate, @Force, @Principle, @NewTotal" +
            ")";

    using (conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())
    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DealerCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = DealerCode;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = InvoiceNo;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = InvoiceDate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemIdentityCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = ItemIdentityCode;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PurchasingPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = PurchasingPrice;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DiscountRate", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = DiscountRate;
        //...

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Script", "alert('Records Successfuly Saved!');", true);
}
```

What you were doing with the StringBuilder and Format strings there was *totally* inappropriate, thanks to a little thing called Sql Injection. It's kind of important, so you should definitely do some reading about it.

I also see that you're trying to group the inserts into a single batch. That's nice, but thanks to connection pooling it doesn't really get you much. It's also harder to do with correct query parameterization. It's not impossible, though, so I'll show you an example now using the other method signature, which makes it a bit easier:

```
private void InsertRec(DEL_PurchasesLines1[] linesToInsert)
{
    const string sqlBase =
            "INSERT INTO DEL_PurchasesLines1 (" +
              "(DealerCode,InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,ItemIdentityCode,PurchasingPrice,DiscountRate,Discount,IssueMode,Qty,Total,ExpireDate,BatchNumber,UploadedStatus,InsertedDate,UploadedDate,Force,Principle,NewTotal)" + 
            " VALUES ";

    const string valueBase = 
              "{0}(@DealerCode{1}, @InvoiceNo{1}, @InvoiceDate{1}, @ItemIdentityCode{1}, @PurchasingPrice{1}, @DiscountRate{1}, @Discount{1}, @IssueMode{1}, @Qty{1}, @Total{1}, @ExpireDate{1}, @BatchNumber{1}, @UploadSTatus{1}, @InsertedDate{1}, @UploadedDate{1}, @Force{1}, @Principle{1}, @NewTotal{1})";

    var sb = new StringBuilder(sqlBase);
    if (DEL_PurchasesLines1.Length > 1) sb.Append("(")
    var delimiter = "";
    for (int i = 0;i<DEL_PurchasesLines1.Length;i++)
    {
         sb.AppendFormat(valueBase, i, delimiter);
         delimiter = ",";
    }
    if (DEL_PurchasesLines1.Length > 1) sb.Append(")")

    using (conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())
    using (cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn))
    {

        for (int i = 0;i<DEL_PurchasesLines1.Length;i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DealerCode" + i, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = linesToInsert[i].DealerCode;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceNo" + i, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = linesToInsert[i].InvoiceNo;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceDate + i", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = linesToInsert[i].InvoiceDate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemIdentityCode" + i, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = linesToInsert[i].ItemIdentityCode;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PurchasingPrice" + i, SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = linesToInsert[i].PurchasingPrice;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DiscountRate" + i, SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = linesToInsert[i].DiscountRate;
        //...
        }
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of some nasty code. I don't know if you are new to programming but you should use a Stored Procedure for this where the procedure defines the 14 or so parameters that need to be passed in as arguments. This will guide your code so that you add parameters for the parameterized stored procedure call, each argument will need to be strongly typed and this will guide you to make the right conversions for each column value of your table. You should also create a C# class that defines, as public properties all your table column values. Excuse the VB.NET but you will get the idea with this simple Data Access Layer (D.A.L) example snippet, the UpdateOffer could be renamed AddUpdateOffer and this could check to see whether the record exists or not by passing in the record id to the AddUpdate stored procedure if it is an update, if the record id is null the stored procedure knows to do an insert else update:

```
 Public Class Offer

        Public OfferID As Integer
        Public PropertyID As Integer
        Public AgentUserID As Integer
        Public AgentName As String
        Public BuyerUserID As Integer
        Public BuyerName As String
        Public BuyerType As String
        Public Offer As Integer
        Public NetOffer As Integer
        Public ClosingCost As Integer
        Public Allowances As Integer
        Public RepairCosts As Integer
        Public TotalCredits As Integer
        Public OfferType As String
        Public OfferDate As String
        Public ProxyOffer As Integer
        Public NetProxyOffer As Integer
        Public ResultResponse As SUBMIT_OFFER_RESULT
        'Public ResultAcceptedOffer As Integer
        Public ResultAcceptedNetOffer As Integer
        'Public ResultHighestOffer As Integer
        Public ResultHighestNetOffer As Integer
        Public Notifications As ArrayList = New ArrayList
        Public EarnestMoneyDeposit As Integer
        Public DownPayment As Integer
        Public TypeOfFinancing As String
        Public OfferStatus As String
        Public Note As String
        Public Visble As Boolean = True
        Public OfferStatusChangedDate As DateTime
        Public EstimatedCloseDate As DateTime
        Public SourceType As String

        Public Sub GetOffer(ByVal offerID As Integer)

            Dim offerDB As OSP.DataAccess.OfferDB = New OSP.DataAccess.OfferDB
            Dim rs As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
            rs = offerDB.GetOffer(offerID)
            Do While rs.Read
                Me.OfferID = offerID
                Me.PropertyID = rs("PROPERTY_ID")
                Me.AgentUserID = rs("AGENT_USER_ID")
                Me.BuyerUserID = IIf(IsDBNull(rs("BUYER_USER_ID")), 0, rs("BUYER_USER_ID"))
                Me.Offer = rs("OFFER")
                Me.NetOffer = rs("NET_OFFER")
                Me.TotalCredits = rs("TOTAL_CREDITS")
                Me.ProxyOffer = rs("PROXY_OFFER")
                Me.OfferType = rs("OFFERTYPE")
                Me.OfferDate = rs("OFFER_DATE")
                Me.DownPayment = IIf(IsDBNull(rs("DOWN_PAYMENT")), 0, rs("DOWN_PAYMENT"))
                Me.EarnestMoneyDeposit = IIf(IsDBNull(rs("EARNEST_MONEY_DEPOSIT")), 0, rs("EARNEST_MONEY_DEPOSIT"))
                Me.TypeOfFinancing = rs("TYPE_OF_FINANCING")
                Me.BuyerName = GlobalFunctions.DefaultString(rs("BUYER_NAME"))
                Me.BuyerType = GlobalFunctions.DefaultString(rs("BUYER_TYPE"))
                Me.AgentName = rs("OFFER_BY_NAME")
                Me.OfferStatus = GlobalFunctions.DefaultString(rs("OFFER_STATUS"))
                Me.Note = GlobalFunctions.DefaultString(rs("NOTE"))
                Me.OfferStatusChangedDate = IIf(IsDBNull(rs("OFFER_STATUS_CHANGED_DATE")), Me.OfferStatusChangedDate, rs("OFFER_STATUS_CHANGED_DATE"))
                Me.Visble = IIf(IsDBNull(rs("VISIBLE")), True, rs("VISIBLE"))
                Me.EstimatedCloseDate = IIf(IsDBNull(rs("ESTIMATED_CLOSE_DATE")), DateTime.MinValue, rs("ESTIMATED_CLOSE_DATE"))
            Loop

            Try
                If Not rs.IsClosed Then
                    rs.Close() : rs = Nothing
                End If
                If Not offerDB Is Nothing Then
                    offerDB.Dispose() : offerDB = Nothing
                End If
            Catch : End Try

        End Sub

        Public Function UpdateOffer() As Integer

            Dim offerDB As OSP.DataAccess.OfferDB = New OSP.DataAccess.OfferDB
            Return offerDB.UpdateOffer(Me)

        End Function
End Class

 Public Class OfferDB
        Implements System.IDisposable


        Dim db As SQLDatabase

        Public Sub New()
            db = New SQLDatabase(GlobalSettings.GetDefaultConnectionString)
        End Sub

        Public Sub Dispose() Implements System.IDisposable.Dispose

            If Not db Is Nothing Then
                db = Nothing
            End If

        End Sub

  Public Function GetOffer(ByVal offerID As Integer) As SqlClient.SqlDataReader

            Dim dbCommand As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("OSP_GET_OFFER")
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@OFFER_ID", SqlDbType.Int, offerID)

            Try
                Return db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim rethrow As Boolean = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "EXCEPTION_CRITICAL")
                If (rethrow) Then
                    Throw
                End If
            End Try


        End Function


        Public Function UpdateOffer(ByVal offer As OSP.Offer) As Integer

            Dim dbCommand As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("OSP_UPDATE_OFFER")

            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@OFFER_ID", SqlDbType.Int, offer.OfferID)
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@BUYER_USER_ID", SqlDbType.Int, offer.BuyerUserID)
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@OFFER", SqlDbType.Int, offer.Offer)
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@TOTAL_CREDITS", SqlDbType.Int, offer.TotalCredits)
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@OFFER_TYPE", SqlDbType.VarChar, offer.OfferType)
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@OFFER_DATE", SqlDbType.VarChar, offer.OfferDate)
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@TYPE_OF_FINANCING", SqlDbType.VarChar, offer.TypeOfFinancing)
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@DOWN_PAYMENT", SqlDbType.Int, offer.DownPayment)
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@EARNEST_MONEY_DEPOSIT", SqlDbType.Int, offer.EarnestMoneyDeposit)
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@OFFER_STATUS", SqlDbType.VarChar, offer.OfferStatus)
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@NOTE", SqlDbType.VarChar, offer.Note)
            If Not offer.OfferStatusChangedDate = DateTime.MinValue Then
                db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@OFFER_STATUS_CHANGED_DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime, offer.OfferStatusChangedDate)
            End If

            Try
                Return db.ExecuteScalar(dbCommand)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim rethrow As Boolean = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "EXCEPTION_CRITICAL")
                If (rethrow) Then
                    Throw
                End If
            End Try

        End Function
End Class
```